# What is the reality of vacuum state in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum

Consider a free field in QFT.

Suppose we are in the vacuum state.

It makes sense to me, mathematically, how the average value of the field is zero and the uncertainty is infinite in a fixed point.

But physically not so much. Rather unclear.

How to imagine a physical thing like a field to be on average zero in a fixed point and infinitely uncertain or varying?

I see that the zero average value in vacuum is helpful to imagine a no particle state but what about the infinite uncertainty in vacuum. Isn't it nonsense?

Also related is this the same thing often described as quantum fluctuations?

Comment: See [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) for your quantum fluctuation question.

Comment: It's not clear what the precise question here is. Physical theories are *models* of reality. QFT is a model that predicts the results of experiments amazingly well, but doesn't lend itself well to "intuitive" or classical understanding. "How to imagine X?" is an opinion-based question, and the question of whether or not QFT is a "consistent" model of reality depends on your definition of "consistent".

Comment: QFT does not predict that the uncertainty is infinite. Which uncertainty would that be, anyway?

Comment: I am referring to page 31 in the Tong's lecture notes here on the infinite fluctuations in a fixed point: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf

Comment: In one point? Of course that will give you both mathematical and physical nonsense. That's a completely unphysical question.

Comment: So are you implying Tong's notes on this calculations for vacuum state of the field  are misleading?

Comment: **How to imagine a physical thing like a field** Without  dealing with the rest of your question, that sentence alone would prompt me to ask how you mentally visualise a field? For more information on virtual particles/ fluctuations , I would read https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/ and https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/quantum-fluctuations-and-their-energy/

Comment: Very nice explanation indeed!

Comment: If he comes out with an infinite number? That's pure intellectual nonsense. Have you seen how hard they have to work at LHC to produce 1TeV "fluctuations"? Why would they need to do that if nature gave infinity to us for free?

Comment: I have not seen that in LHC. Any reference? Also edited my question above. My problem is to better visualize the nature of vacuum in QFT.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what Tong is saying. The infinite energy arises because we have an infinite number of oscillators and $\tfrac{1}{2}h\nu$ energy per oscillator and obviously this gives the ground state infinite energy. We generally just subtract off this infinity and take the ground state as zero, which is perfectly reasonable since we can only measure energy differences anyway. This infinity has nothing to do with uncertainty.

Comment: I see your point. But the question is not about the Hamiltonian and energy. I mean here the field operator itself in a fixed point given the vacuum state is zero on average whereas the fluctuations are infinite. This for me is hard to physically imagine.

Comment: It's because of distributions vs functions. The crux of the fighting between mathematician and physicists.